# Copy block of excel fields based on criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for a quick way to fill some fields based on a the following condition. (See image)

I have a list containing 3 columns. I need to fill Column C depending on the letter in Column A. When I go to C34 I would like to automatically search the rows above and based on the letter in Column A copy the 11 names from the latest occurrence above. So in C34-C44 the names from C1-C11 would get copied as a block.

Is there a function in Excel that can do that?

[image: Data Screenshot is here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple VBA macro with two **FOR loops** to solve your issue:

```
Sub CompleteRows()
Dim lastrow As Long 

lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'finds last row in column A

For x = 1 To lastrow 'loop that starts with value 1 and goes all the way to the value of lastrow
    If Cells(x, 3).Value = "" Then 'if value in column C is empty then continue on 
        For y = 1 To lastrow 'second loop that runs through the same range
            If Cells(y, 1).Value = Cells(x, 1).Value And Cells(y, 2).Value = Cells(x, 2).Value Then
            'If the value of the first column and the value of the second
            'column for both values match, then add value to column C 
                Cells(x, 3).Value = Cells(y, 3).Value
                Exit For 'Exit loop if value was found
            End If
        Next y
    End If
Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! Would you mind explaining what the script does?

Comment: See comments. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful!

Comment: No worries @Tom, don't forget to accept my answer (click on the check mark beside the answer) if it was helpful.